# What is the difference between Travis' head movement constraint and Rizzi's relativized minimality?

Tags: syntax, generative-grammar, movement

What is the difference between the head movement constraint of Travis (1984), and the relativized minimality of Rizzi (1990)?

Comment: Hey, Joey, did you see my answer about "semantic negativity" the other day? If so, did it help you? Any feedback on it? Also, I see you've asked this question again using another account on Linguistics. FYI, that's not necessary.

Comment: Hey, Dan, I will get back to you on "semantic negativity" later on. I am fairly new in this website, I didn't know that SE has so many branches